# Run WorkBook Calculate Formulas as last process

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

how I can run Formulas Calculate as last proces when WorkBook is opened ?
I mean when all data are already load, user gave permission to load external data from others WorkBook etc.

I already tryed with

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Calculate
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
Application.Calculate
End if
End Sub
```

When I run Excel file and click F9 (Calculate Formulas) then it's work.
How I can run Application.Calculate when all externals links(data from others workbook) are already loaded ? I think it could help
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you open the workbook use

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

When you are about to close the workbook after completing all the work use

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("wrkSheetName").Calculate
```

for each worksheet.

Comment: main point is that i want to calculate again everything before I start work on WorkBook.